# Flutter SliverAppBar add widget to collapsed part

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently developing a flutter mobile app by using sliver appbar and I want to add some widget to collapsed app bar.and also make background color to gradient. when I tried to add by using leading property it creates overflow and also the widget displays in the flexspacebar.

[image]

The above image is before scroll.

[image]

and this one is after scroll and I want to add some widget in the center of the blue part.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:rehove/Widgets/sliver_card.dart';
import '../Widgets/action_button.dart';
class UserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme _textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return
      AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
          value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light

          ),
    child: Scaffold(

      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(


            collapsedHeight: 320,
            pinned: true,
            leadingWidth: 200,
            leading: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:32),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap:()=>{
                  Navigator.pop(context)
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    Text('Back',style: _textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 16
                    ),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            expandedHeight: 450,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(

              background:  Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/images/user.png',
                  width: double.infinity,
                 height: double.infinity,
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                  Align(
                    alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 102,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color:Color(0xffD9D9D9).withOpacity(0.6),
                      child:Padding(
                        padding:const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text('Liya Dereje',style: _textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: 20
                                ),),
                                Text('LiyaDereje2@gmail.com',style: _textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                                    color: Color(0xfff7f7f7),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 12
                                ),)
                              ],
                            ),
                           ActionButton(label: 'Edit Profile',
                             height: 38,
                             width: 20,
                             onPressed: () {  },)
                          ],

                        ),
                      )
                    ),
                  )
              ]
              ),
            ),
          ),
           SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child:Column(children:  [
                const SizedBox(height: 40,),
                Row(
                 children:  [
                 const  Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 1,)),
                   Text('Setting',style: _textTheme.bodySmall?.copyWith(
                     fontSize: 14,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                   ),),
                  const Expanded(child: Divider(thickness: 1,)),
                 ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.notifications_outlined,title: 'Notification',amount: '4',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.donut_small,title: 'Reports',amount: '4',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.email_outlined,title: 'Email',amount: '5',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.description_outlined,title: 'Terms of',amount: '3',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.accessibility_new_rounded,title: 'Accessibility',amount: '4',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),

                SliverCard(icon: Icons.logout,title: 'Logout',amount: '4',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.email_outlined,title: 'Email',amount: '5',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.description_outlined,title: 'Terms of',amount: '3',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                SliverCard(icon: Icons.accessibility_new_rounded,title: 'Accessibility',amount: '4',),
                const SizedBox(height: 10,),
              ],
            )

          )
        ],
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is the issue  coming from `ActionButton`?

Comment: no Yeasin, I just want to add some widget inside the center of blue part.

Comment: Seems like i am missing the issue point, only able to get appBar leading issue while I reduce the width

Answer (score 1):

[image]**Step 1:**
First declare the varibale

```
bool lastStatus = true;
ScrollController? _nestedScrollController;
```

**Step 2:**

```
void _scrollListener() {
    if (_isShrink != lastStatus) {
      setState(() {
        lastStatus = _isShrink;
      });
    }
  }

  bool get _isShrink {
    return _nestedScrollController != null &&
        _nestedScrollController!.hasClients &&
        _nestedScrollController!.offset > (30.h - kToolbarHeight);
  }
```

put above method inside the class

**Step 3:**

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    _nestedScrollController?.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _nestedScrollController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



 @override
  void initState() {
_nestedScrollController =
        ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 33.h - kToolbarHeight)
          ..addListener(_scrollListener);

}
```

Put the above method inside the init and dispose

**Step 4:**

```
Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              body: NestedScrollView(
              controller: _nestedScrollController,
              headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                return [
                  TransitionsAppsBar(
         isShrink: _isShrink,

                   ….
            …
                  ),
                ];
              },
              body:  child…
```

Step 5:
Use require code inside the below class

```
class TransitionsAppsBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isShrink;
  final VoidCallback? onBackTap;
  final VoidCallback? onInfoTap;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final VoidCallback onAlertTap;
  final GroupDetailsDTO? groupInfo;
  final bool isOverDue;

  const TransitionsAppsBar({
    Key? key,
    this.isShrink = true,
    this.onBackTap,
    this.onInfoTap,
    this.groupInfo,
    this.onTap,
    this.isOverDue = false,
    required this.onAlertTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<GroupBloc, GroupState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return SliverAppBar(
          elevation: 2,
          backgroundColor: AppTheme.secondaryColor,
          pinned: true,
          collapsedHeight: kToolbarHeight + (isOverDue ? 25 : 0),
          centerTitle: true,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          leadingWidth: 21.w,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          bottom: !isOverDue
              ? null
              : PreferredSize(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: onAlertTap,
                    child: Container(
                      color: AppTheme.primaryColor_100,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            Assets.icOverdue,
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                            color: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Text(
                            StringConstants.groupIsInactive,
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .caption!
                                .copyWith(color: AppTheme.whiteColor),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Text(
                            StringConstants.learnMore,
                            style:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      color: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                    ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
                ),
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Visibility(
              visible: isShrink,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 100.w,
                height: kToolbarHeight,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            groupInfo?.name ?? '',
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        if (groupInfo?.isOverdue ?? false) ...[
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: onAlertTap,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              Assets.icOverdue,
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]
                      ],
                    ),
                    if ((groupInfo?.id ?? 0) != 0)
                      Text(
                        "${(groupInfo?.memberDetails.length ?? 0).toString()} ${StringConstants.loopers}",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .caption!
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 14, color: AppTheme.whiteColor),
                      )
                    else
                      Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          leading: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.h),
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: isShrink,
                  child: ((groupInfo?.id ?? 0) != 0)
                      ? ProfilePic(
                          imageUrl: groupInfo?.image,
                          name: (groupInfo?.name.length ?? 0) <= 3 ||
                                  groupInfo!.isIndividualGroup
                              ? groupInfo?.name
                              : groupInfo?.name.characters.take(3).toString(),
                          picType: groupInfo!.isIndividualGroup
                              ? StringConstants.systemGroup
                              : StringConstants.group,
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ),
              ),
              BackButtonWidget(onBackTap: onBackTap),
            ],
          ),
          expandedHeight: 30.h,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Center(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: !isShrink,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.h),
                    child: ((groupInfo?.id ?? 0) != 0)
                        ? ProfilePic(
                            imageUrl: groupInfo?.image,
                            name: (groupInfo?.name.length ?? 0) <= 3 ||
                                    groupInfo!.isIndividualGroup
                                ? groupInfo?.name
                                : groupInfo?.name.characters.take(3).toString(),
                            picType: groupInfo!.isIndividualGroup
                                ? StringConstants.systemGroup
                                : StringConstants.group,
                            sizeMultiplier: 2.5.h,
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 2.h),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                          child: Text(
                            groupInfo?.name ?? "",
                            maxLines: 2,
                            style:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2!.copyWith(
                                      color: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (groupInfo?.isOverdue ?? false)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, left: 8),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: onAlertTap,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              Assets.icOverdue,
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      else
                        const SizedBox(width: 12),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    child: Text(
                      (groupInfo?.memberDetails ?? [])
                          .getMemberNames(groupInfo?.adminId ?? 0),
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .caption
                          ?.copyWith(color: AppTheme.whiteColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
          actions: [
            Visibility(
              visible: !groupInfo!.isIndividualGroup &&
                  !state.isFetchingGroupDetails,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: onInfoTap,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    Assets.icInfoGroup,
                    height: 25,
                    width: 25,
                    color: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another `Stack` that wraps your `FlexibleSpaceBar` and the widget you want in the middle when collapsed. Try this:

```
flexibleSpace: Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('I\'m in the center'),
      ),
    ),
    FlexibleSpaceBar(
      background: Stack(children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/user.png',
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
              height: 102,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Color(0xffD9D9D9).withOpacity(0.6),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment:
                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment:
                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment:
                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Liya Dereje',
                          style: _textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                              color: Color(0xffffffff),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'LiyaDereje2@gmail.com',
                          style: _textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                              color: Color(0xfff7f7f7),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 12),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    ActionButton(
                      label: 'Edit Profile',
                      height: 38,
                      width: 20,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        )
      ]),
    ),
  ],
),
```